# Having issue in my count function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how many data available are available. This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    count('pincode'), tr.*, t.* 
FROM tinfo t 
LEFT JOIN tutorregistration tr ON tr.tid = t.tsid 
WHERE pincode LIKE '%andhra%';
```

This gives the result `count('pincode') = 11` and stops at only 1 row record. How can I get all records from my query?[image: You can check the image]

you can  check with screen shot

Comment: It should be `count([column_name])` so in your case `count(pincode)`. Without the apostrophes.

Comment: Careful your LEFT JOIN is transposed to an INNER JOIN with that WHERE

Comment: You want to show the count of those records where pincode LIKE '%andhra%'; right? That'll make your result of one record with total count. Isn't it?

Comment: yes boss your are right

Comment: Help me I have not solved yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT tr.*, t.* 
    FROM tinfo t 
    JOIN tutorregistration tr on tr.tid = t.tsid 
    WHERE pincode LIKE '%andhra%'
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT tr.tid, count(pincode) as req_count
    FROM tinfo t 
    JOIN tutorregistration tr ON tr.tid = t.tsid 
    WHERE pincode LIKE '%andhra%'
) b ON a.tid = b.tid;
```

Comment: HI Thanks  Your query is retrieving  only only one result  based on tid.  I tested, once again if you see my question  the query is showing count('pincode') has 11. tid=189, how to see the  11 row in my db I want to use in pagination

Comment: @divyakodeeswaran This query looks like it should work. Can you provide a sample data set from your tables, and the results you're currently getting, and the results you expect to receive? Putting those in your question would be helpful.

Comment: HI cpburnz see the question I have attached the db image with   user3169080  answer

Comment: Have seen my image update with his answer, please tell me what I have to do next

Comment: I am not sure why this query is not working as you expected. Can you give a sample data set from both your tables which satisfy the pincode LIKE '%andhra%' condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle db please use below query to get desired records:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) OVER () total_records,tr.*, t.* 
FROM tinfo t 
left join tutorregistration tr on tr. tid=t.tsid 
where pincode LIKE '%andhra%';
```

Comment: now all the 11 records is in  pincode column name only.

Comment: please accept the answer and vote it up if this post solved your problem.

Comment: Hi I am using mysql .query is not working for me. Any solution please

Comment: The question is asking about MySQL, not Oracle.